# Creating a small program in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program in `Python 3.5` that asks the user to enter a number from 1 to 9. The the program will also guess a number from 1 to 9. If the user guesses the same number correctly, then the program will print `Correct` . Otherwise, the program will print `Wrong`. I wrote a program. Everything went fine with my code. However, when I guessed a number correctly, the program suddenly wrote `Wrong` instead of `Correct`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
print('Enter a number from 1 to 9')
x = int(input('Enter a number: '))
import random
random = print(random.randint(1,9))
if int(x) != random:
    print ('Wrong')
else:
    print ('Correct')
```

Comment: You are assigning `None` to `random`

Comment: It is not advisable to use a variable named random.

Answer (score 2):

You are saving the result of a `print()` call (and masking `random`). `print()` returns `None`, so it will always be unequal to an integer, and therefore always "wrong."

```
import random

print('Enter a number from 1 to 9')
x = int(input('Enter a number: '))
r = random.randint(1,9)
if x != r:
    print('Wrong')
else:
    print('Correct')
```

Also note that I've moved the `import` statement to the top, avoided a second `int()` cast on something you've already done that to, and removed the space between the `print` reference and its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the mistake,

```
random = print(random.randint(1,9))
```

You need to do something like this.

```
random = random.randint(1,9)
print(random)
```

Also, you have already converted the input to int so, you can do just this.

```
if x != random:
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out your mistake is the line

```py
random = print(random.randint(1,9))
```

But why?

`functions` (like `print()` *take* something, *do* something (with it) and *give* something back.

Example:
`sum(3,4)` *takes* 3 and 4, may *add* them and *returns* 7.

`print("Hello World")` on the other hand *takes* "Hello world", *prints* it on the screen but has nothing useful to give back, and therefore *returns* `None` (Pythons way to say "nothing").

You then assign `None` to the name `random` and test if it equals your number, which it (of course) doesn't.